# How do I change the action of a button with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipickerview

I am trying to change where a button leads to depending on the selected row of a picker view. I am trying to display data depending on a certain year and I can make the picker display the available years and change a label to the corresponding year, but how can i make the "go" button I;ve created lead to the correct view controller?

Comment: add a check at the button click method that will lead to the correct view controller based on the year in the label?

Comment: @user2578110,  don't forget to accept, up vote, or post an answer so everyone knows the outcome. Then other will be more likely to answer future questions you have!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you haven't had time to figure this out, maybe you have, but this is what I would do.  You have a text field that you will populate with a picker, call this the "yearTextField."  Then you have a button that you want to change the action depending on the year in question.  Call this "myChangableButton."  This is just for an example, you can call them anything you like.  I put my initial view controller in a navigation view controller to have better control of the views.  For this example I made two different years 1942, and 1971.  They each have their own view controller that I named "FourtyTwoViewController" and "SeventyOneViewController" in my first view controller you will need to import these into the .m file.  Like this..

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FourtyTwoViewController.h"
#import "SeventyOneViewController.h"
```

Also, make sure when you drag out the new view controllers in the storyboard, that you name them as such. And don't forget to use that name as the Storyboard ID, found under the Identity inspector.  Now for myChangableButton I made an action that will bring up whichever view controller you want based on the text in the yearTextField like this..

```
- (IBAction)myChangableButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([_yearTextField.text isEqual: @"1942"])
    {
        FourtyTwoViewController *ftvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FourtyTwoViewController"];
        //[self presentViewController:ftvc animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ftvc animated:YES];
    }
    else if ([_yearTextField.text isEqual: @"1971"])
    {
        SeventyOneViewController *sovc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SeventyOneViewController"];
        //[self presentViewController:sovc animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sovc animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Watch Out!" message:@"Put in valid date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

The line of code that I commented out will bring up a modal transition, but I prefer a push since that gives you a great back button.  That's it.  I hope this helps you on your project.  Make a comment if you have any questions, and good luck. And WELCOME! to SO!!

EDIT #1

Here is a sample of how I set the initialUrl in a viewcontroller that I pushed.

```
VideoViewController *vvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoViewController"];
vvc.initialUrlString = urlString;
vvc.descriptionString = descriptionString1;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vvc animated:YES];
```

I imported VideoViewController into the first view controller.  And VideoViewController has two properties called initialUrlString and descriptionString.  In the first view controller I have two properties called urlString and descriptionString1, these are set in the first view controller during another method and then passed into the second.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer!  I sorta tried what you suggested but had some issues. What I really want to do now is this: I have one view controller with the picker view that lets you select the year and a go button. That go button leads to another viewcontroller(both are attached to the same view controller files..sorry if my terminology is off). That second viewcontroller has a webview that i want to display an html file(locally stored) of the info for the specified year. My ultimate question is how do i change what html file is displayed depending on the selection of the pickerview.

Comment: @user2578110 You will need to pass the file path for the html file onto the second view controller.  Let's say your second view controller is called "SecondViewController", it will need a property called say "htmlPath."  When you select the year in the first view controller set a variable in the first view controller to the html path you want to display.  Then when you call the second view controller use this line after you get a reference to the second view controller.  "secondViewController.htmlPath = whateverYouCalledThePath;"  Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Also, You will need to take the "whateverYouCalledThePath" and pass that to the web view to get it to load.

Comment: I am pretty new to this so I don't quite get what you are doing. Currently i have a property as nsstring named htmlname in my view controller that is showing the file(call it webview). I have imported webview into my original view controller(call it selectorview). I have tried typing webview.htmlname in order to refer to the variable, but it throws an error. I also tried to synthesize the htmlname variable in the selectorview implementation file. If you know a good visual tutorial or youtube video for this that would be great.

Comment: @user2578110, before you do webview.htmlname make sure you reference your webview by doing webview *wv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"]; You are telling your selectorview "Hey there is another view controller called webview"  But you do need to make sure you call your webview, webview in the identity inspector in the right hand column in Xcode.  I don't know of any good visual tuts for this. Sorry.

Comment: Actually I just found this.  A youtube on passing data.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFLK_1Shwe8

Comment: That was actually perfect. Probably another stupid question, but where do i put that reference? The header or implementation file? If the implementation file then where in it?

Comment: oh also, when i put that reference in, it came up with an error on the "self" part

Comment: @user2578110, the reference goes in the implementation file. And you can place it where ever you are trying to get to the next view controller.  The self part might have thrown an error if you do not have your selectorview in a navigation controller.  You can do this by selecting selectorview in the storyboard and then go to the editor menu and select embed in.

Comment: does it have to be in a navigation controller?

Comment: @user2578110, if you want to use the self line of code, yes it does.  If you don't have it in a nab controller use the line that I commented out with the // in front. [self present....]  But that will force you to make a button or action that then dismisses the webview view controller.

Comment: ok i can put it into a navigation controller, but the self thing is still causing an issue

Comment: @user2578110, Add your code to your original post, I will take a look tomorrow!  Also, now that you have changed some code around it is always good to clean and build your project.  Go to the product menu and go down to clean, then try running it again.

Comment: Hey i watched that video and did some tweaking and got it worked out so it works great even without the navigation controller. thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hey, sounds great!  If I helped, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark by the top left of my answer, and also clicking the up arrow. That's how we get rep points and let people know the answer was solved. Good luck!